# How to make different button action based on gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a task to make different button action based on value on a gridview's column.

This is the code I need to run when the value of the "Status" column is "Completed"

```
string controllerPath = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ControllerPath"];
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = controllerPath;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
//psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Process proc = Process.Start(psi);

string msg = "AdHoc update executed";
showSaveNotification(msg);
```

and this is the code when the "Status" column is showing "Waiting" or "Pending".

```
string msg = "You can't update for now.";
showSaveNotification(msg);
```

I'm new with this stuff so I need your help.

Thank you in advance. And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx, what have you tried?

Comment: ah yes, if-else. but i need help with some sql command to get the value from my gridview.

Comment: 'gridview.Rows[0].Cells[0]', so you really did not try anything?

Comment: not yet. but you give me some inspiration.

Comment: that is not how this site really works, get inspired by `gridview.Rows[0].Cells[0]`, if you want me just to write some code for you its 150eur/hour

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link. may be it could help you. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: that's not what i expected. i was expecting some sql command stuff inside if-else.